# Duvidas Sobre Lentidão Java WS e remover o warn

Tags: java, java-ee, eclipse

1) Tenho uma duvida sobre a lentidão de um web service REST que estou montando.
Na comunicação do cliente até a resposta do servidor demora alguns segundos.
O que já filtrei:
-Todos os processos que a função faz são quase instantâneos, perceptível apenas pelos print
-Print abaixo demonstra o momento da demora, que é: entre os WARN e o inicio da execução do sistema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) Outra dúvida, é como corrigir esses WARNs exibidos

POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.projeto</groupId>
  <artifactId>Projeto</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Projeto Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>  
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-mvc-jsp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.grizzly/grizzly-http-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
</dependency>


    <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Projeto</finalName>
    <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>    
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Esse "warning", pode ser a dependência do seu "server" que não esta resolvida, poderia postar seu "pom.xml" ou qualquer outra biblioteca que utilize o log4j como logback. Esse jar que ta esperando essa dependência ser resolvida é da jboss, ta utilizando o wildfly, hibernate, spring? São alguns que utilizam o logback do log4j

Comment: Acrescentei o pom

Comment: Para o warning acrescenta isso ae pra ver se sai, o hibernate para fazer loggin precisa dessa dependecia pra rodar slf4j-to-log4j
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

Veja se deu certo.

Comment: Continuou aparecendo

Comment: O Erro então e no seu arquivo hibernate.properties ele está na sua pasta "src/" ?

Comment: Não achei o arquivo na pasta src/ e nem dentro das pastas de la (como resources/META-INF, só há o persistence.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como corrigi o erro do WARN:

1) Criei um arquivo lo4j.properties em src/main/resources
2) Acrescentei o seguinte código:

```
#Log to Console as STDOUT
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n
#Log to file FILE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.append=true
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c %3x - %m%n

#Root Logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, file
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685510/log4j-warning-while-initializing